# Reverse Multiplication

Tags: java, math, biginteger, modulus

I have the following number; let's call it number one

> -1757151608

then I have a second number, let's call it unknown

> 94507795

and finally, I have the product, let's call it number two

> -1000

If I multiply the first two numbers in form, I get the answer as -1000.
Problem is, I have the number one and number two at my disposal, but I need to get the unknown from this.

I've tried using the `BigInteger` class and a few of it's functions with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "DWORD"? A 32-bit integer, or a 64-bit integer, or something else? This probably has to do with integer overflow; you'll need to find the unknown number so that when you multiply it with the given number, the result will be -1000 through integer overflow.

Comment: Since op forgot the post is about java, not c++/WinAPI: DWORD is a 32bit unsigned integer

Comment: It sounds like you want to multiply number two by the multiplicative inverse of number one mod 2^32?

Comment: Forget I ever said dword. Doing a println of the multiplication of number one and unknown results in -1000, I need to work backwards in order to find out the unknown while knowing number one and two.

Comment: What does it mean to multiply numbers "in form"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to reverse this multiplication.

First, let's take the two's complement of the first number.

```
3904635256 = 2147483648 - -1757151608
```

Next, we'll multiply the second number

```
369018468323820520 = 3904635256 * 94507795
```

Now, here's the tricky part.  We convert the product to hex, and drop the digits larger than a 32 bit integer.

```
51F0457800003E8 (hex) = 369018468323820520 (decimal)
800003E8 = 51F0457800003E8 moved to a 32 bit signed integer
```

Now, we convert the hex value back to decimal

```
2147484648 (dec) = 800003E8 (hex)
```

Finally, we take the two's complement of the decimal

```
-1000 = 2147483648 - 2147484648
```

Since we threw away the `51F0457 (hex)`, we have no way of getting that back.  The reverse of this operation is impossible.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be impossible, thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to multiply -1000 by the multiplicative inverse of -1757151608 modulo 2^32; see, e.g., [the calculation in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1757151608+%2A+94507795+mod+2%5E32%29+-+2%5E32).

I have written a program which I believe correctly calculates the answer to your question, when one exists.

```
public class InverseMultiplication {

  // multiplicative inverse of a multiplied by b mod 2^32
  public static long invertAndMultiply(long a, long b) { 
    // take out common factors of 2
    while (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0) {
      a /= 2;
      b /= 2;
    }
    long m = 256L*256L*256L*256L; // modulus is 2^32
    long r = m;
    long nr = a;
    long t = 0;
    long nt = 1;
    while (nr != 0) {
      long q = r/nr;
      long tmp;
      tmp = nt; nt = t - q*nt; t = tmp;
      tmp = nr; nr = r - q*nr; r = tmp;
    }
    if (r > 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException(a + " has no inverse");
    t = (t*b) % m;
    while (t < Integer.MIN_VALUE) t += m;
    while (t > Integer.MAX_VALUE) t -= m;
    return t;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long twoPow32 = 256L*256L*256L*256L;
    int n1 = -1757151608;
    int n2 = -1000;
    long unk = invertAndMultiply(n1,n2);
    System.out.println(unk);
    long pro = n1 * unk % twoPow32;
    if (pro > Integer.MAX_VALUE) pro -= twoPow32;
    System.out.println(pro);
    int pro1 = -1757151608 * 94507795;
    System.out.println(pro1);
  }
}
```

There are a few important points to note, however. If your "number one" is odd, there is a unique answer which the program will find quickly.

An even "number one" will not have an inverse mod 2^32, so in general you will be out of luck in that case. However, if your "number two" is also even, you can keep dividing both by 2 ("taking out common factors of 2") until one or both are odd. Hopefully "number one" is odd, in which case you'll get an answer; if "number one" is even after taking out all common factors of 2, you won't get any answer. In that case there is no answer.

If there is an answer in the even case, there's more than one answer. If you run my program, you'll see that it arrives at a different answer from yours.

Please check it out and let me know whether it works the way you expect.